# c++ how to write a newline into CURLOPT_

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, iostream

I have tried all the obvious methods to write a newline at the end of the file, at the end of the loop from a CURLOPT_ stream.
I do not get an error, but also no newline is ever written.
How to you insert a newline into CURLOPT_  ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
        size_t written;
        written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
        return written;
}



int main(void)
{
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;

        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155");

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                        curl_easy_strerror(res));

        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen ("/home/coinz/cryptsy/myfile.txt","a+");
        if (pFile!=NULL)
        {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pFile);
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                std::cout << pFile << std::endl;
                //pFile << "\n\r";
                fclose (pFile);
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++, have you tried `fstream`? It will work for the syntax you're attempting on `pFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `fprintf(pFile, "\n");` instead of the `<<` operator.

Comment: that did it. one min and I will click the button. it's time delayed.

Comment: The idea is to not mix certain C and C++ functions and objects. A good example would be `malloc` should be with `free` and `new` should be with `delete` since they are made to work with each other.

Comment: That writes a newline to the output file, I think you should seriously try to fix this question's title and description. This is not writing anything "to CURLOPT_" as that doesn't make sense!

Comment: that side of it wasn't working for me so the title is correct. If it was just a 'write new line' issue, then 'std::cout << pFile << std::endl' should of worked. CURL was throwing the monkey wrench. The title is accurate and Nard nailed it.

Comment: In other words, Daniel is saying that you should not post questions on SO unless you know the **exact** cause of your problem, which essentially disallows questions such as `why is my code printing weird values?` due to uninitialized variables and `why is my code crashing at this point?` due to memory access violation.